# c++ string += operator memory consequence

Tags: c++

I am wondering how `std::string` handles its buffers in terms of memory.

As I understand it `char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];` will be allocated on the stack.  So if it begin reading into that buffer

```
string result;
oFile.read(buf, BUFFER_SIZE-1);
bytesRead = oFile.gcount();    //get # of chars read into buffer
buf[bytesRead] = '\0';         //terminate with a null
sFinal += buf;
```

So my question is mainly on the `+=` operation.  When the buffer is concatenated with the string,  does it need to reallocate more memory? As a follow up question does this memory need to be a continuous block? If so, would that allocation be a heap or stack operation?

Comment: `string` is not a `char []`! This is C++, not C.

Comment: @9er  Interview is not an exam. Never do any assignments in an interview.

Comment: Do employers really expect SW engineers to know the underlying machinations behind standard classes?

Comment: @KevinDTimm, I usually want them to understand it on the high level.

Comment: @KevinDTimm I would not expect you to be able to just implement a standard class but you should know how the underlying mechanics behave.

Comment: Normally, it will be necessary to reallocate memory. However, if you use [`reserve()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/reserve) to avoid repeated reallocations.

Comment: @9er  For optimization class std::string can reserve initially some memory in the object itslef. for the buffer. But the size of this memory is small.  So for large strings the class allocates dynamically memory and copies there the elements from the rpeviously allocated buffer.

Comment: None of the C++ containers is using the C-function `reallocate` (which is mostly useless, anyway) and none of the C++ containers is stack based, besides std::array. A sequential container (eg,: std::string, std::vector) might have a capacity greater than the actual size of elements.

Comment: @SergeyA - and NathanOliver - thanks for the information. I've been doing Java for a very long time (C & python also) and would like to believe I'm pretty good at them. I'm not a C++ aficionado and so that world might be different. IOW, In the java world I might be able to posit about the underlying process but almost certainly couldn't answer the above question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::string` is an object in C++, then implicit constructors get char pointers as string to support C's string literals.
If you care about memory a `std::ostringstream` can be more useful that the + operator:

```
std::ostringstream result("hello");
result << " world!";
std::cout << result.str();
//prints "hello world!"
```